# Driver Installation Problem with MySQL ODBC using MacOS Big Sur

Tags: macos-big-sur, mysql-odbc-connector

[image]

Is there an another way to install the MySQL Connector/ODBC Drivers?

Comment: did you read this page, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-installation-binary-osx.html

Comment: @yusufhayırsever yes, it's not working